# How to access User Profile's friends in ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am building a simple social media app. AND i am trying to build a feature of adding users into `post` using `ManyToManyField`.

I am trying to access `profile friends` in `Post's model instance "add_user"` for tagging user.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile",blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    add_user = models.ManyToManyField(User.profile.friends.all())
```

I am new in django and I have no idea how can i access `user's friend` in Post's model instance.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Show us your complete code that generates the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give a queryset as an argument for a ManyToManyField, just a class name.

```
add_users = models.ManyToManyField(User.profile.friends.all()) # you can't do this.

add_users = models.ManyToManyField(User) # Do this.
```

You shouldn't place you logic in your model's definition.
Do that in your views.

EDIT:
I suggest you use a ModelChoiceField and do the filtering logic there:

```
class AddFriendForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = kwargs.pop('user')
        except:
            user = None
        super(AddFriendForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['friend'].queryset = user.profile.friends.all()

    friend = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.none())
```

And then in your view you initialize it like this:

```
def your_view(request):
    form = AddFriendForm(user=request.user)
```

Comment: BUT it will access all the users in `template` which will hard to find my friends in it, BUT i am trying to access only friends in `m2m` field

Comment: It is keep showing **NoneType' object has no attribute 'profile'** when i try to access the form in browser

Comment: It is now working sir, Thanks BUT it is not showing `ManyToManyField` it is showing like `choice field`

Comment: When i use **ModelMultipleChoiceField** then it is working. Thank you very much for your Help sir, Are there any `limitations` of using this ?

Comment: No, you just have to initialize the form properly.

Comment: Okay Thanks again for your Precious Time

Comment: How can i access tagged friend in `PostDetail` template ? and In Admin ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do

```py
add_users = models.ManyToManyField(User.profile.friends.all())`
```

Because the models is evaluated once, and need to be non mutable values

You need to do :

```py
add_user = models.ManyToManyField("Profile",blank=True)
```

And dont forget to add on your `ManyToManyField`:

```py
related_name="XXX", null=True
```

Comment: BUT it will access all the users in `template` which will hard to find my friends in it, BUT i am trying to access only friends in `m2m` field

Comment: dont mix data architecture and data visualization :), this will show no friends if you dont add them